# Lectura de archivos en C++. ¿Como funciona un flujo de entrada?

Tags: c++, array, string, fstream

Leyendo un código me he encontrado con un ejemplo curioso de lectura de archivo en C++, creo que es curioso porque en el se utilizan hasta cuatro objetos distintos, con distinto nivel de abstracción de la cadena de caracteres. Yo entiendo hasta ahi, que el primer objeto contiene mas información y va tamizando la cadena en cada asignación hasta quedarse con el array puro de caracteres. Pero tengo curiosidad por saber que pasa realmente en cada asignación, ¿que extrae y que elimina?

Vemos la lectura del archivo a un **ifstream**, de un ifstream lo pasa a un **stringstream**, del stringstream extrae un **string**, y del string extrae una cadena de caracteres pura, un **array**.

```
// Open file
std::ifstream shaderFile(fileName);
if (shaderFile.is_open())
{
    // Read all the text into a string
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream << shaderFile.rdbuf();
    std::string contents = sstream.str();
    const char* contentsChar = contents.c_str();

    // Create a shader of the specified type
    outShader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    // Set the source characters and try to compile
    glShaderSource(outShader, 1, &(contentsChar), nullptr);
    glCompileShader(outShader);

    if (!IsCompiled(outShader))
    {
        SDL_Log("Failed to compile shader %s", fileName.c_str());
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    SDL_Log("Shader file not found: %s", fileName.c_str());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `shaderFile`? ¿De dónde sale esa función o clase?

Answer (score 2):

> Vemos la lectura del archivo a un **ifstream**, de un ifstream lo pasa a un **stringstream**, del stringstream extrae un **string**, y del string extrae una cadena de caracteres pura, un **array**.

¿Por qué hace algo tan complicado? Es difícil de decir, cada problema puede ser aproximado de diferentes maneras, en el caso de tu ejemplo "*vuelca*"<sup>1</sup> todo un archivo en un flujo de texto (es decir: `stringstream` o flujo `stream` de texto `string`) porque de leer desde archivo con formato podría sólo leer palabra a palabra usando el operador de extracción con formato ([`>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)) o línea a línea con [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Una vez tiene el contenido del archivo en un flujo de texto, fuerza la lectura de los datos **copiando**<sup>2</sup> el contenido del flujo en un objeto de texto con la función [`stringstream::str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str); dado que el compilador de *shaders* espera una cadena de caracteres (no un objeto de texto) debe extraerse la cadena de caracteres interna de `std::string` mediante [`std::string::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), función que devuelve una cadena de caracteres al estilo [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>3</sup> (justo lo que espera el compilador de *shaders*).

Personalmente, veo todo esto complicado de más, yo copiaría de archivo a texto con un iterador:

```
// Si el archivo no se puede abrir, la expresión equivale a 'false'.
if (std::ifstream shaderFile(fileName))
{
    // Leemos todo en un objeto de texto:
    using iterator = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;
    std::string contents{};
    contents.reserve(1024u * 1024u); // Reservamos espacio para minimizar re-alojamientos.
    std::copy(iterator(test), iterator(), std::back_inserter(contents));

    // Accedemos a la cadena de texto interna:
    const char *const contentsChar = contents.c_str();
    //          ^^^^^
    // Añadido un 'const' adicional, por seguridad.

    // Create a shader of the specified type
    outShader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    // Set the source characters and try to compile
    glShaderSource(outShader, 1, &(contentsChar), nullptr);
    glCompileShader(outShader);

    if (!IsCompiled(outShader))
    {
        SDL_Log("Failed to compile shader %s", fileName.c_str());
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    SDL_Log("Shader file not found: %s", fileName.c_str());
    return false;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>En realidad no vuelca el archivo en un flujo de texto si no que asigna al flujo de texto el búfer del archivo, el resultado es el mismo, pero es un matiz importante.

<sup>2</sup>Observa que devuelve una instancia de `std::string` no una referencia.

<sup>3</sup>Una cadena de caracteres finalizada con el carácter nulo `'\0'`.